# Arm7 GUI options for Ubuntu Mate: Mist? Parity

Tags: mist, parity

I am running a geth arm7 node on a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Mate installed.  I would like to have a GUI wallet for this node.  What are my options?

Is there a arm7 version of Mist or Parity?

Comment: that preferably doesn't building it myself from source...

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://github.com/ethcore/parity-snappy/wiki/Parity-on-ARM)?

Comment: no haven't tried building from source

Comment: this is not building from source; just dowloading a release.

Comment: thanks.  No I haven't tried this. sorry I didn't see that there was a link.

Comment: So this works, however I am having problems setting the chain to classic (I want to withdraw my whitehat dao).    I have tried running --chain=classic and --chain=homestead-dogmatic.  Is it true that this will only work with v1.3 of parity?  and if so then there is no arm build for 1.3 yet?

Comment: First things first. Please feel free to answer your own question since you figured out the arm release for parity. In addition, if you have another question, please [just do so](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). And finally, parity 1.1.0 should default to classic, but that is an assumption, did you sync yet?

Comment: I am syncing with geth to classic and want to attach to parity.  Why would 1.1.0 default to classic??

Comment: Because all pre-fork releases do 'not know' about the fork and default to the non-forked chain. But be careful, there might be glitches. Compare block hashs.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/paritytech/parity-snappy/wiki/Parity-on-ARM has the build that will run on ARMv7.

Answer (score 0):

Parity has ARMv7 releases targeted for devices like the Raspberry Pi 3.

You can get them from the [releases page](https://github.com/paritytech/parity/releases/latest), note they are tagged with `armhf`.

*Disclosure, I work for Parity.*